# Name for the following combination of two Bernoulli trials ? $m$ trials with success prob $p$ and $n$ trials with success probability $1-p$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, terminology

I was wondering whether there is a name for the following distribution:

There are two coins, the first coin is heads with probability $p$, the second coin is heads with probability  $1-p$.
What is the chance of getting more heads than tails from $m+n$ tosses ($m+n$ is odd) where, $m$ tosses are made with the first coin, and the remaining $n$ are made with the second coin?

$P \left(m,p,n,1-p\right)  =\sum\limits_{h=\frac{m+n+1}{2}}^{m+n}\left(
\sum\limits_{
\begin{array}{c}
k+l=h \\ 
0\leq k\leq m \\ 
0\leq l\leq n 
\end{array}
}\binom{m }{k}\cdot \binom{n}{l}\cdot p^{k}\cdot \left( 1-p\right) ^{m-k}\cdot \left( 1-p\right) ^{l}\cdot p^{n -l}\right) $

This is related to a bigger question I have posted before and I thought the complexity of the bigger question might stop people from commenting on this specific probability.

Is it something that has a name? Is there any other way of writing the same problem?

Thank you for reading.

[Link to the bigger question that I hope to solve in the long run.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689488/white-black-toys-are-placed-into-boxes-75-has-high-white-chance-rest-black)

Comment: I removed the [tag:probability-theory] tag. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: I'm no expert in such terminology, but my searches turned up nothing more specific than probability distribution for sum of two independent random variables (which in your case happen to be Bernoulli trials).